# GreyScale buffer with CImg

Tags: cimg

my goal is to create a unsigned char buffer filled with 0-255 grey scale color.
each cell in the buffer is 0-255 (no RGB).
i would like to exract from grey scale pic only one parameter (0-255 grey scale).
how to do so with CImg?

thanks,
jose.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'one parameter' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the luminance of your input sRGB image, like this, in CImg:

```
CImg<unsigned char> luminance = RGB.get_RGBtoYCbCr().channel(0);
```

where `RGB` is the name of your RGB image.